# Trying to verify a token in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

After a user signs up i send them an email with a link containing a token and their email address. When they click that link im trying to verify the token by getting the token object and email value from the url query string then finding a matching token in my database. Howver i keep getting a null value for the token variable(when i use it in inner function) even though it is stored in the outer function.

```
//------------------------------------------------- TOKEN VERIIFICATION ------------------------------------------------ 
function verifyToken(req, res)
 {

    var email = req.query.email
    var token = req.query.token

    Token.findOne({ token: token },

        function (err, token) {
            console.log(token)
            if (!token || token === undefined)
                res.render('verify', { notif: 'We were unable to find a valid token. Your token may have expired.' });

            // If we found a token, find a matching user
            console.log("token was found")

            User.findOne({ _id: token._userId, email: email }, function (err,) {
                if (!user) res.render('verify', { notif: 'We were unable to find a user for this token.' });
                if (user.isVerified) res.render('verify', { notif: 'This user has already been verified.' });

                // Verify and save the user
                user.isVerified = true;
                user.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) { res.render('verify', { notif: err.message }); }
                    res.render('verify', { notif: 'The account has been verified. Please log in.' });
                });
            });
        });
}


// ------------------------------------------------- END OF TOKEN VERIFICATION ---------------------------------------------
exports.registerUser = registerUser
```

I call this function above in my server.js like this:

```
app.get('/verify', function (req, res) {

    userController.verifyToken(req, res);
    //res.render('verify', { title: "Email Verification" });
})
```

I sucessfully get the email and token value then store them in variables but when i try to access them in the Token.findOne's respective function they are NULL. please help me

***EDIT****

this is the schema for my token

```
const tokenSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },
    token: { type: String, required: true },
    createdAt: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now, expires: 43200 }
});
```

this is what it looks like in the database:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f640985f6dcb40988328a57"), "_userId" : ObjectId("5f640985f6dcb40988328a56"), "token" : "487f7b22f68312d2c1bbc93b1aea445b", "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-09-18T01:12:37.339Z"), "__v" : 0 }
```

***ALSO***

Now when I set Token.findOne({token:token})
i get this error : TypeError: Cannot read property '_userId' of null

Comment: `token` does not exist in the database.

Comment: it does exist in the database

Comment: If `token = req.query.token` is defined but the `token` from the `.findOne()` callback, that means what you're querying does not exist. If that's the case, double check your token to match is being saved properly in your db once the user signs up

Comment: Show your evidence, or print our `err` instead of `token`

Comment: ok I just checked my database and tokens are being saved correctly

Comment: when i print error i get null

Comment: i edit the post to show token

Comment: `console.log("---" + req.query.token + "---")`. Return when `token` is null to stop process.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong.

the token model was not being registered as a schema because i was using:

```
const tokenSchema = new mongoose.Schema
```

even though I was already defining 'Schema' by using :

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
```

so it was fixed by doing:

```
const tokenSchema = new Schema
```